# AVKit – Video clips loop just 2 times

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller, avqueueplayer, avkit

I have got four video clips and I want to play them endlessly. But my `AVQueuePlayer()` loops all the videos just 2 times and then stops.

**How to make them play endlessly**?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let player = AVQueuePlayer()
    let clips = ["001", "002", "003", "004"]
    private var token: NSKeyValueObservation?
    var avPlayerView = AVPlayerViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addAllVideosToPlayer()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        self.addAllVideosToPlayer()
    }

    func addAllVideosToPlayer() {
        avPlayerView.player = player

        for clip in clips {
            let urlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: clip, ofType: "m4v")!
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlPath)
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
            player.insert(playerItem, after: player.items().last)

            token = player.observe(\.currentItem) { [weak self] player, _ in
                if self!.player.items().count == 1 { self?.addAllVideosToPlayer() }
            }
            avPlayerView.showsPlaybackControls = false
            player.volume = 0.0
        }
        present(avPlayerView, animated: true, completion: { self.player.play() })
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure. But i think they are playing twice because you are calling the `addAllVideosToPlayer` twice in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`. And the issue might be the callback that is never firing to call the `addAllVideosToPlayer` recursively.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28509900/2395636) answer can help you. The only issue is that it is in `Obj-C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I deleted `viewDidLoad()` method and placed `present()` function into `viewDidAppear()`.

Here's how it looks like:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    self.addAllVideosToPlayer()
    present(avPlayerView, animated: true, completion: { self.player.play() })
}
```